# Block internet access for a specific Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, permissions

I want to use a Chrome extension called [Focusalarm](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/focusalarm/ilcajdpmgfbeggnpffmohcopdgpcdndh?hl=en).

It asks for the permission "Read your browsing history", which the author tells me it needs to find out which tabs are open.
Can I block it from sending this data across the internet?

Comment: This message doesn't mean that the extension is "sending your data across the internet". When an extension uses the `Tabs` permission it shows this warning. You can see what permissions trigger different warnings in the developer documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/permission_warnings/#permissions_with_warnings). The extension still could send data to a server, but you will need to review the [code](https://github.com/yaeluria/Focusalarm) to check that.

Comment: Open `chrome://extensions` page for this extension and switch its `Site access` to a manual list, then add a nonexistent site there.

Comment: @cactus12 erm, yes, the extension could send data to a server, and I don't have access to the code, that's why I asked if I can block it from sending data across the internet

Comment: @wOxxOm no, site access allows me to limit which sites it can read, not limit access to the browsing history

Comment: It prevents the extension from sending the info outside, which is a way to implement what you need.